# How can I map two lists into a dictionary from lists being passed into function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

I am trying to map two list into a dictionary. I know how to do this but I am having a problem when the lists are being passed from functions, only the first values from each list get mapped. i have tried every method of mapping:

```
def main():
    pop = [34372,37821,45673,67100,69100,70245]
    years = ['2012','2013','2014','2016','2017','2018']
    highest_year_change(years,pop)

def highest_year_change(years,pop):

    year_pop_dict = {}

    year_pop_tuples = zip(years,pop)
    for key, value in year_pop_tuples:
        year_pop_dict[key] = value

    print(year_pop_dict)
```

output:
    {'2012': 34372}

I first tried: `year_pop_dict = dict(zip(years,pop))`
but the same results . only when the lists were not passed between functions was the dictionary created as intended.
`

Comment: `dict(zip(years, pop))` returns `{'2012': 34372, '2013': 37821, '2014': 45673, '2016': 67100, '2017': 69100, '2018': 70245}`.

Comment: Works for me - when `main` is called `{'2012': 34372, '2013': 37821, '2014': 45673, '2016': 67100, '2017': 69100, '2018': 70245}` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume both the list are of same length hence the below solution :)

```
pop = [34372,37821,45673,67100,69100,70245]
years = ['2012','2013','2014','2016','2017','2018']

def convert_to_dictionary(pop, years):

    dic = {}
    length = len(pop)
    for i in range(0, length, 1):
        dic.update({years[i]:pop[i]})

    return dic

result = convert_to_dictionary(pop, years)
```